# primefaces dataTable pagination does not work with "first" option

Tags: primefaces

I am using primeFaces 5, i have `dataTable` with 11 rows (pagination: 10 rows per page), so i have two pages. First page has 10 rows, second 1.

When i try to load last page with:

> `<p:dataTable fist="1">`

I see last 10 rows.

How to get only 1 row on last page when setting "first" more then 0, for example:

> `<p:dataTable fist="1">`

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "first" attribute does not specify the page, but the Index of the first row to be displayed. So in your case if you have 11 elements, you would have to set first to be 11.